# Criar um objeto do tipo Stream a partir de uma string

Tags: c#, .net, string, stream

Preciso criar um objeto do tipo `System.IO.Stream` a partir do conteúdo de uma `string`. Essa minha `string` está num arquivo **Resource.resx**. Recupero ela assim:

```
string xml = ResourcesRel.pt_BR;
```

Preciso usar um componente que possui um método `Load()`. Esse método tem duas sobrecargas: uma que aceita o caminho físico do arquivo, e outra que aceita o `Stream`.

Dá pra criar um objeto `Stream` a partir da *string*?

Comment: Basicamente não seria isso http://stackoverflow.com/a/1879470/2221388?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você pode converter para bytes e depois para `MemoryStream` que é um objeto que herda de `System.IO.Stream`.

```
string conteudo = "Teste";
byte[] array = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(conteudo);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(array);
```

Comment: Vou aceitar essa resposta pois foi a primeira, e é mais simples(menos linhas de código). Aparentemente não tive nenhum problema com ela.

Answer (score 6):

Você pode usar o [`MemoryStream`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0). Você tem que ver se precisa fazer alguma conversão antes ou não.

```
using System.IO;
using System;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var texto = "meu texto aqui";
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
        writer.Write(texto);
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;
        var reader = new StreamReader(stream); //aqui já está consumindo o stream
        var novotexto = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(novotexto); //só pra mostrar funcionando
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/L1Flh0). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/awmcfZ). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/StringToStream.cs).

Se preferir pode fazer isto:

```
var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("meu texto aqui"));
```